# What is the area of shaded region which is lies between outer and inner circle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, area

There is a outer circle with radius 2r and another inner circle with radius r whose center is the middle of big circle.As depicted in the following figure.

[image: Circle]

[Foo graph Image](http://fooplot.com/#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--)

There is a sector of 120 degree in inner circle which leads to shaded part between outer and inner circle. What is the area of shaded circle in terms of r ?

i.e. What is the value of K ?

Comment: What have you been able to determine about the figure so far, for example the lengths of any segments or the angles of any arcs?

Comment: If we can find angle of segment then we can solve question easily , The major problem is with angle which is made at outer circle.

Comment: @john: I'd try to center the polar coordinates in the center of small disc and the polar axis to be the dotted line. Then integrate

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Can we do using geometry it would be great for me

Comment: @john You are right: "angle which is made at outer circle" is a good place to start. I see there is already an answer that starts that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WLOG let $r=1$.

Let us use a coordinate system centered on the large circle. Then the oblique line on the right has equation $x=\sqrt3(y-1)$ and meets the circle $x^2+y^2=4$.

Solving the quadratic equation, the intersection point is $(\dfrac{\sqrt{39}-\sqrt3}4,\dfrac{\sqrt{13}+3}4)$.

Hence, the aperture angle of the large sector

$$\theta=2\arctan\left(\frac xy\right)=1.19873\cdots \text{rad}=68.6821\cdots°.$$

The requested area is the difference between the large and the small sector and two triangles having base $1$ and height $x$.

$$K=\frac\theta2\,2^2-\frac\pi31^2-\frac22x=4\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{39}-\sqrt3}{\sqrt{13}+3}\right)-\frac\pi3-\dfrac{\sqrt{39}-\sqrt3}4=0.222026268\cdots.$$

Comment: Can you check about Area it should be  " large  sector - small sector - 2 * triangles" . Triangle is not of height 1.  It's the triangle made by center of outer circle and center of inner circle and intersection point . In this case answer will get changed .

Comment: @john: I said base $1$ (small radius) and height $x$ (altitude, distance from the intersection point to the vertical diameter). What's your answer ?

Comment: yeah it's same .

Answer (score 2):

Draw a line from the centre of the larger circle to the left-most corner of the shaded region. This has length $2r$. We then have an obtuse angled triangle with largest angle $\frac {2\pi}{3}$, due to symmetry.
Let $\theta$ be the angle between the radii.

Using the sine rule, we have $$\sin\frac {2\pi}{3}=2\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}-\theta)$$
Expanding and rearranging, we have $$\sqrt3\cos\theta-\sin\theta=\frac {\sqrt3}{2}$$
Now a compound angle transformation gives $$2\cos(\theta+\frac {\pi}{3})=\frac {\sqrt3}{2}$$
Thus $$\theta=-\frac {\pi}{6}+\arccos(\frac {\sqrt3}{4})$$
Whereupon the area can also be written as: $$\frac 12(2r)^22\theta-\frac 13\pi r^2-2(\frac12)(2r)(r)\sin\theta$$ which simplifies to $$r^2\left(-\pi+4\arccos(\frac{\sqrt3}{4})+\frac{\sqrt3}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{39}}{4}\right)$$
This is the same as the answer already found, but in a slightly neater form.

Comment: Could you detail the first step, this is a little terse ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: yes sorry about that. My skills with MathJax are still somewhat limited, and I don't know how to post a diagram. I will amend my first post to give more detail as soon as I can

Comment: @YvesDaoust: does this make it clearer?

Comment: Yep, understood now. The crux is solving that $r/2r$ triangle.

Answer (score 1):

You can also easily solve the problem by rotating the figure by $90^o$ clockwise so that the dotted line coincides with the x-axis & center of outer circle at the origin. Thus, equation of the outer circle: $x^2+y^2=4r^2$ & the equation radius above x-axis: $y-0=\tan60^o(x-r)$ or $y=\sqrt{3}(x-r)$ solving the equation for intersection point of line & outer circle as follows $$x^2+(\sqrt{3}(x-r))^2=4r^2 => 4x^2-6rx-r^2$$ now, solving for x-coordinate, we get $$x=\frac{6r\pm\sqrt{36r^2+16r^2}}{8}=\frac{r(3\pm \sqrt{13})}{4}$$ Consider a right triangle above x-axis obtained by joining the intersection point (in I-quadrant) to the center of outer circle, we get semi-aperture angle $\alpha$ at the center of outer circle as follows $$\alpha=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac{r(3+\sqrt{13})}{4}}{2r}\right)=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{8}\right)=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{42-6\sqrt{13}}}{8}\right)$$

Hence, the shaded area is $$=\frac{1}{2}(2\alpha)(2r)^2-2\left(\frac{1}{2}(r)(2r)(\sin\alpha)\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)(r^2)=r^2\left(4\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{8}\right)-\frac{\pi}{3}-\left(\frac{\sqrt{42-6\sqrt{13}}}{4}\right)\right)$$ Hence, we get $$K=4\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{8}\right)-\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{42-6\sqrt{13}}}{4}\approx0.222026268$$

Answer (score -1):

something like this:
$$
2r^2\left(\int_0^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}2} \left(\sqrt{4-x^2} - 1 - \sqrt{1-x^2} \right)dx + \int_{\frac{\sqrt{3}}2}^{\frac{\sqrt{13}-1}4} \left(\sqrt{4-x^2} - 1-\frac{\sqrt{3}x}2 \right)dx \right)
$$